# $ \{ x : ( \inf_{n \geq k} f_n)(x) > a \} = \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} \{x: f_n(x) > a \} $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Pick $x \in \{ x : ( \inf_{n \geq k} f_n)(x) > a \} \iff ( \inf_{n \geq k} f_n)(x) > a \iff f_n(x) > a \forall n \geq k$. Therefore, $x \in  \{y : f_n(y) > a \}$ for all $n \geq k$. And this holds iff $x \in \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} \{y : f_n(y) > a \}$. Hence, we have $$ \{ x : ( \inf_{n \geq k} f_n)(x) > a \} = \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} \{x : f_n(x) > a \} $$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. And the two sets are not equal in general. Hint: the second $\iff$ in your proof is wrong.

Comment: Can you explain? I don't see why it is wrong the second iff

Comment: Try $f_n(x)=a+1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\inf_{n\geqslant k}f_n(x)\gt a$, then for all $n\geqslant k$, we have $f_n(x)\gt a$. But the converse doesn't need to hold: take $f_n(x):=\frac 1n$ and $a=0$.